# Validation rule with Regex

Tags: validation-rule

I am creating a validation rule using regex , can someone help here. If the company picklist value is 'Electrical', then only Account Number can have hyphen. for other company picklist values , hyphen cannot be included for account number.

```
AND((REGEX( Account_Number__c , "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$")),
ISPICKVAL( Company__c , "Electrical"))
```

The above rule is not working. Really appreciate your help. thanks

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). When you say that it isn't working, what exactly isn't working and what were you expecting? Could you please [edit] your question to add more details.

Answer (score 1):

Validation rules trigger when they are true, so you need to make it true when you'd like the error.

```
NOT(ISPICKVAL(Company__c, 'Electrical')) && FIND('-', Account_Number__c) > 0
```

This says that when the account isn't electrical, and the number contains a hyphen, give an error. Other constructs would work too, but this is probably the most straight forward.

Alternatively:

```
NOT(
  IF(ISPICKVAL(Company__c, 'Electrical'),
    REGEX(Account_Number__c, '^\\w*$'),
    REGEX(Account_Number__c, '^(\\w|-)*$')
  )
)
```

But I think that's a bit harder to read and possibly overkill.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your prompt response . this is working in some cases but not for all cases. like whenever I am creating new record and not putting hyphen for account number when company is electrical, it is still allowing me to save the record.  Can you please help me. thanks

Comment: hello this is working on update but when I create new record , it does allow me to save record even when no hyphen is typed for account no.